# Error encountered The action 'show' could not be found for PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby on rails in windows.. I am following some guide through youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI_VnnOLSKY) but I encountered error "The action 'show' could not be found for PostsController" when I am defining the index method

NOTE: The version of my ruby on rails in windows is latest. This is my first method I will do and to display my first view but it gives me an error.

Question: Should I put the show method to my PostsController?

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resource :posts
  root "posts#index"
end
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

Comment: Here is another tutorial you might want to check out :- https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: Okay sir.. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `resource :posts` to `resources :posts` and also change the 'application' into 'default' located at 'application.html.erb' file. You will need to add a `show` method such as:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

and a view as well in `show.html.erb`

Comment: Sir,  I changed the resource into resources :posts but give me a new error. The error is "ExecJS::ProgramError in Posts#index" ypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10
              
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

Comment: Do you mean defaults? I tried to change the resources into defaults :posts, it give me again a new error "TypeError no implicit conversion of Symbol into Hash Extracted source (around line #3):
1
2
3
4
5
6
              
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  defaults :posts
  root "posts#index"

end

Comment: Try changing `application` in: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` to `default`